# Need a program that I can set a pre assigned region to take a screen capture of

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I need the program to "save" the location and width of the region in pixels and then have the ability to take a screen shot of that region with a command. For example, I could set a region that starts at 300x400 and has an area of 200x500, then I can save that area and take a screenshot of that area with a command. This is on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), which has a feature to take a screenshot. The download link is at the very bottom of that page.

✓ Windows
✓ Free of cost

That tool has a verb *savescreenshot* which takes a file name, x and y coordinate and width and height like so:

```
>nircmd savescreenshot "test.png" 50 50 200 100

>dir /b *.png
test.png
```

Now, you probably don't want a single file name. You can fix that using the magic (or hell) of Windows Batch programming and generate a file name from date and time:

```
>nircmd savescreenshot "%DATE% %TIME:~-11,2%%TIME:~-8,2%%TIME:~-5,2%.png" 50 50 200 100

>dir /b *.png
07.06.2019 211728.png
test.png
```

You don't need to do it in DOS mode, you can also create a batch file with the following content:

```
@echo off
start nircmd cmdwait 200 savescreenshot "%DATE% %TIME:~-11,2%%TIME:~-8,2%%TIME:~-5,2%.png" 50 50 200 100
```

That will wait 200 ms for the DOS window to disappear and then take the screenshot.

Comment: that program sounds exactly like what I need

Answer (score 0):

There is a commercially available program known as [SnagIt](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) which does offer the ability to perform the task you describe.

The program is exceptionally well-equipped and easily customizable. You can define the reference figures you've placed in your question in one of the capture panels. Either the Print Screen key or a user-selected key is then used to capture the screen. The file generated is saved to a user-defined location with a user-defined filename that indexes with each capture command.

SnagIt calls the feature the "all-in-one" capture on the web page.